# PackagesNotFoundError when trying to install `puma` with Conda

Tags: conda, failed-installation, conda-forge

I am trying to download the puMA (porous microstructure analysis) library using the steps on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/nasa/puma).

But the solving environment step keeps failing, and I get the error:

> The following packages are not available from current channels: puma.

Here's the full output:

```bash
(base) lgoldberg@Lucias-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda create -y --name puma -c conda-forge puma
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - puma

Current channels:

 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to

  https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I tried reinstalling `conda-forge` and making sure it's at the top of my list of channels, but I'm pretty lost - any idea of how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Now building for osx-arm64

At the time of original posting, that particular package was not available for the **osx-arm64** platform, however, [now it is](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/puma). Subsequent to [a request for such builds to be added](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/pull/4488) (or "*migrated*" in the Conda Forge terminology), it has been made available. OP’s original command should now work.

### Workaround: Emulating osx-64

For documentation purposes we will retain the following workaround, which should still work and would be applicable for any other packages not yet migrated. Namely, **osx-arm64** users can create and use **osx-64** environments and packages with some extra commands. You need [Rosetta 2 installed on your system](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) for this to work.

```bash
## create the environment using packages from osx-64 subdir
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n puma_osx64 -c conda-forge python=3.10 puma

## configure the environment to always use osx-64 subdir
conda activate puma_osx64
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

Whenever you want to install new packages in this environment you need to first activate it. That is, running a command like `conda install -n puma_osx64 foo` without the environment activated could break it.

Note that `python=3.10` is specified simply to speed up solving. You are welcome to specify a different version, though I would probably not use `python=3.11` yet because there are [still hundreds of packages](https://conda-forge.org/status/#python311) that have not yet *migrated* to that.